# app crash in appfog using node js mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, backbone.js, cloud-hosting, appfog

I have an app hosted in appfog using node-express and mysql( and backbone js in the client side), it works fine in localhost but when deploy the app  works fine for a moment and after a time crash( if i restart in the console of appfog admin the same thing happens)
this is part of code for connection mysql

```
var mysql = require("mysql")

var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
var creds = env['mysql-5.1'][0]['credentials'];
console.log(creds)

var client = mysql.createConnection({
  host: creds.host || "localhost",
  user: creds.user,
  password: creds.password,
  port: creds.port,
  database: "savelinks"
});
```

The code in app.js

```
var express  = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var port = 9000;
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var app = module.exports = express();

console.log(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES)

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);  
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 });

 var server  = require("http").createServer(app)
  app.get("/", function(req,res){

    res.render("index");
 });

 /*
  * GET ALL LINKS ON LOAD PAGE
 */
 app.get("/links", function(req, res){

     links = db.client.query("SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY created DESC", function(err, result){
      if(!err){
         res.json(result)
      }
   });
});
// more routers
 app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || port, function(){
    console.log("server run in port " + port)
 });
```

This is the log that app fog shows

```
events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/savelinks-0-ca19c96d36d4701debe7fe46752707c5/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:73:13)
    at Socket.onend (stream.js:66:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:417:51)
```

Any idea for solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue in production, but not on my personal development machine. My node server uses node-mysql with connect on an Ubuntu VM. My node server would crash and restart now and then throughout the day with the same kind of error you are seeing.

The following approach explained on the node-mysql GitHub page worked to solve the problem for me:

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#server-disconnects